# dispatch_after with a sliding or resettable delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am showing a UIView to display information about map features that a user has marked for other purposes, such as deleting or editing. When a feature is marked, i am showing a UIView containing info and an undo option. Showing the the UIView for a fixed amount of time is done and working, however, I would like the delay to have a sliding expiration, that is, if the user selects another map feature to mark, the delay should reset itself and the UIView should stay visible for the full amount of time specified. What I am looking for is a sliding expiration. My code thus far:

```
double delaySeconds = 15;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delaySeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self toggleUndoViewToShow:NO];
});
```

So, my delay time is 15 seconds and if, during this 15 seconds, another feature is marked, I would like the view to remain visible for the full delay time. How might I go about this? thanks!

Comment: Did you consider use NSTimer instead? Using GCD requires to write much more code for this task. It will look like: 1. map selected 2. cancel previous timer (if any) 3. schedule new timer for 15 sec. 4. if nothing selected - timer fires and hides your window 5. if new item is selected within 15 sec - goto 2. The main point is that the only 1 or 0 timers are scheduled at certain point in time and it is cancelled as soon it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timer dispatch source. Create it with `dispatch_source_create()`, passing `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER` as the type. Call `dispatch_source_set_timer()` to set the start time. To emulate `dispatch_after()`, which only runs its task once, use `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` for the interval. Call `dispatch_source_set_event_handler()` to set the task to perform when the designated time arrives. Also, the task needs to cancel the source using `dispatch_source_cancel()` to clean up the source. Call `dispatch_resume()` on the source to allow it to go (it's created in a suspended state).

You can use `dispatch_source_set_timer()` at any time to adjust the time at which the task should run. You can also cancel it at any time.

Since this is somewhat more complex than `dispatch_after()`, you can wrap it up in a helper to set this up for you. The caller of the helper function would submit a task block that's ignorant of the need to cancel the source. Your helper would wrap that in a task that calls the supplied block and then does the `dispatch_source_cancel()`.

---

For the very simple case you need, the above may be overkill. You could also do something like:

```
__block int savedTaskID;
if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    savedTaskID = ++self.currentTaskID; // an integer property on your view
else dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    savedTaskID = ++self.currentTaskID;
});

double delaySeconds = 15;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delaySeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (savedTaskID == self.currentTaskID)
        [self toggleUndoViewToShow:NO];
});
```

If you want to delay the toggling, simply repeat the above steps. Since that increments `currentTaskID`, when previously-submitted tasks run, they do nothing. This is a little wasteful, since the neutered tasks still stick around and eventually run, but it doesn't sound like it will happen much.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you would need to cancel an existing block scheduled to execute after certain delay and schedule the equivalent block with fresh delay of 15 seconds. [This](http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2011/12/cancel-dispatch_after/) should help you with canceling a delayed block scheduled to run.